# Add fields live using the first select option in query

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, ajax

http://www.onderdelenzoeker.nl/

On this website when you select a year it shows a few more fields to choose from and the options are filtered for just that year without refreshing the page or anything.

I cannot figure out how to do this, can someone help me out?

Comment: Its using ajax called on select change handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to hook into the `change` event, and load the other options there. If you have to load those other options dynamically, you'll have to make an AJAX request.

---

Check out this video tutorial, which explains exactly how to do this:

Remy Sharp: [**Populate Select Boxes**](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/populate-select-boxes/).

Comment: I took a look at the video and its exactly what I want, thanks a lot!